# How to force shift in Yacc?

Tags: bison, yacc, jison

I have the following constructs as part of a yacc grammar (or rather jison, but the two share the same common base):

```
Type
    : IDENT
    | Type "[" "]"
    | Type "*"
    | "func" "(" Types ")" "=>" Type
    ;

Types
    : /* No arguments */
    | Type /* Single argument */
    | Types "," Type /* Multiple arguments */
    ;
```

This is of course a simplified example, but it should give the general idea and shows the problem in action. I want to parse constructs such as `Foo[]`, `Foo*`, `Foo*[]` into `(Foo)[]`, `(Foo)*`, `((Foo)*)[]` respectively.

However, Yacc rightfully complains that it doesn't know what to do when it encounters the following construct:

```
func (A, B) => C[]
```

It can be parsed into either `func (A, B) => (C[])` or `(func (A, B) => C)[]`. I would of course like it to be the first (since I have a `( Type )` construct for the second case). Is there any way I can tell yacc (or jison) that I want to shift if it encounters this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the last `Type` production a precedence, either with a `%prec` declaration and a pseudo-terminal, or using the default, which is the precedence of `=>`, the last terminal. Then make sure the precedence of the `[` token is higher. (You'll also have to make the precedence of `*` higher than `=>`, to solve the other shift-reduce conflict.)

There are other solutions, but that one is the simplest.

In fact, bison/yacc/jison/etc. always prefer shift in a shift-reduce conflict, so you don't need to do anything to get a shift. The precedence rules will suppress the warning, but you could use an `expect` declaration to do that, as well.

Comment: Yep, fiddling with `%left` and `%prec` did indeed resolve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @B.Alfred There is another ambiguity  with `*`, or at least that's what I got with Zaach's online jison tool. I edited the answer to include that.